# How to get the author of an entry?

Tags: users, entry, admin

I have one user group created, several users in it excludes admin.
I've tested it includes admin to that user group, but with no effect.

If you create an entry in channel as admin and check at front end for author of the entry, you'll see not admin, but actually the data of a first user created in Craft.

Is it done on purpose? If so, What is it, so I understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the author's username of an entry via it's [entry model](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel) like so:

```
{{ entry.author }}
```

Comment: I went through `craft.users` . Oh, learning whole life